# Fastest operations on object/array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Pretty new to JS here and the array operations I'm used to in PHP obviously do not work in JS.
I have an array of objects with a date (timestamp), a duration (number) and a mode (number):

```
  {
    "date": 111, //Not proper timestamp, just for the purpose of the question
    "duration": 1.8333333333333333,
    "mode": 2
  },
  {
    "date": 111,
    "duration": 3.4,
    "mode": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 111,
    "duration": 2.9833333333333334,
    "mode": 2
  },
  {
    "date": 222,
    "duration": 5.666666666666667,
    "mode": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 222,
    "duration": 8.266666666666667,
    "mode": 2
  },
  {
    "date": 222,
    "duration": 0.5666666666666667,
    "mode": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 333,
    "duration": 9.25,
    "mode": 2
  }
]
```

What I'm looking for is to sum the durations of objects that share the same date and mode.
ex:

```
{
    "date": 111, //Not proper timestamp, just for the purpose of the question
    "duration": 3.4,
    "mode": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 111,
    "duration": 4.81,
    "mode": 2
  },
  {
    "date": 222,
    "duration": 6.2,
    "mode": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 222,
    "duration": 8.26,
    "mode": 2
  },
  {
    "date": 333,
    "duration": 9.25,
    "mode": 2
  }
]
```

I have tried creating and manipulating 2 dimensional arrays without success.

For instance looping on my initial data set and updating a result_array like so:

```
result_array[mode][date]+=duration;
```

Thx

Comment: Please share what you have already tried.

Comment: Use a Map to sum it up and then remap the map to your final list of objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: `Object.values(durations.reduce((obj, dur) => {
  const key = \`${dur.date}-${dur.mode}\`;
  if (obj[key]) {
    obj[key].duration += dur.duration;
  } else { 
    obj[key] = { ...dur };
  }
  return obj;
}, {}))`

Comment: @epascarello that works perfectly! Thx!

Comment: @epascarello I'm analyzing your answer to understand the technique. Could you explain to me the difference between obj[key] and obj in your answer? Thx.

Comment: not sure what you mean the difference.... Basic of reduce, you have an object, you set a property in the object, you return the object,

Comment: I read the docs today. Well made and comprehensive, I got my explanation.